# Create instance of class within another class

Tags: ruby, rspec

Forgive me if my question isn't completely clear. I have been awake for way too long and I'm feeling a little brain dead.

I'm doing a Ruby exercise and I can't figure out why my rspec test isn't passing for something I thought would work.

```
require 'date'

class Product
    attr_accessor :photo_src, :promotion, :initial_date
    attr_reader :default_photo, :default_price, :current_price

    def initialize(name, photo, price)
        @name = name
        @default_photo = photo
        @photo_src = photo
        @default_price = price
        @current_price = price
        @initial_date = Date.today.yday
        @promotion = false
    end

    def price_change(sale_price)
        calculator = RedPencilCalculator.new(self)
        if promotion
            if sale_price > @current_price
                calculator.end_promotion!
            elsif sale_price < (@default_price - (@default_price * 0.3))
                calculator.end_promotion!
            end
        else
            calculator.start_promotion!
        end
        @current_price = sale_price
    end
end

class RedPencilCalculator
    attr_accessor :promotion_start, :product

    def initialize(product)
        @product = product
    end

    def start_promotion!
        if start_promotion?
            product.promotion = true
            product.photo_src = "redX.png"
            @promotion_start = Date.today.yday
        end
    end

    #would need to run daily
    def end_promotion?
        promotion_duration
        if @duration == 30 || @duration == 335
            end_promotion!
        end
    end

    def end_promotion!
        product.promotion = false
        product.photo_src = product.default_photo
        product.initial_date = Date.today.yday
    end

    private

    def calculate_range
        @min_discount = product.default_price - (product.default_price * 0.05)
        @max_discount = product.default_price - (product.default_price * 0.3)
    end

    def start_promotion?
        calculate_range
        @max_discount <= product.current_price && product.current_price <= @min_discount && Date.today.yday - product.initial_date >= 30
    end

    def promotion_duration
        current_date = Date.today.yday
        @duration = current_date - @promotion_start
    end
end
```

Rspec

This doesn't work:

```
describe Product do
  let(:shoes) { Product.new("shoes", "item.png", 100) }

  it 'should change the photo_src and promotion attribute if applicable' do
    allow(shoes).to receive(:initial_date) { 100 }
    shoes.price_change(75)
    expect(shoes.promotion).to eq(true)
    expect(shoes.photo_src).to eq("redX.png")
  end
end
```

This does:

```
describe Product do
  let(:shoes) { Product.new("shoes", "item.png", 100) }
  let(:calculator) { RedPencilCalculator.new(shoes) }

  it 'should change the photo_src and promotion attribute if applicable' do
    allow(shoes).to receive(:initial_date) { 100 }
    shoes.price_change(75)
    calculator.start_promotion!
    expect(shoes.promotion).to eq(true)
    expect(shoes.photo_src).to eq("redX.png")
  end
end
```

So it seems to me that the start_promotion! method call in the price_change method just isn't working.

Comment: That should be fine. Post your calculator class?

Comment: That's what I thought. I'm obviously making some dumb mistake somewhere. I just can't figure it out and staring at it is no longer productive.

Comment: So just to make sure, the code runs fine, but you think there is a logic error somewhere that is making the results wrong?

Comment: Are you getting an error message? if so - a stacktrace would be really useful too :)

Comment: Plus the test... so we can see what behaviour is expected of your code.

Comment: Style Note: you have an accessor called `promotion` but you are still calling things directly on the `@promotion`... you should only use the `@promotion` in the initializer - after that, just use `promotion`. Likewise, you should use `@product` in the calculator, and add an accessor for it so from then on you can just call `product`

Comment: Actually... it's plausible that this might be why it's failing... have a go at changing it to always use the accessor instead and see if it helps.

Comment: Tried it and still no go. Thanks for the tip though. And no error message. Just expected true / got false

Comment: Tried "it" ? which it :)
Have you updated the code to use accessors? if so - can you update the code in your question to match ?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I put a puts inside of `start_promotion?` like this:

```
p "got past calc range: #{@max_discount.inspect} and #{@min_discount.inspect} and #{product.current_price}"
```

and got:

```
"got past calc range: 70.0 and 95.0 and 100"
```

given that the following line checks that current-price is *less* than the min-discount... 
that's the line you've gotta check/fix to make things work

Comment: Duh... I knew it was something stupid that I missed. Thank you so much for your patience with me. I really appreciate the help.

Comment: You're welcome. I too get stupid-brain after I've been bashing my head against something for a while... just comes with the territory ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a specific answer to your bug but some suggestions on how to pinpoint the problem.

You're testing too much in one unit test. There's so much that can go wrong it's hard (as you've found) to track down where the bug lies. Even if you work it out now, when something changes down the track (as it inevitably will) it will be at least as difficult as it is now to debug.

Simplify the initializer. It should only set @name, @photo, @price. The other instance variables should be methods (write tests unless they're private).

You suspect `RedPencilCalculator#start_promotion!` has a bug. Write a test to eliminate that possibility.

With more tests in place, the bug will eventually be cornered and crushed!

Lastly - this is easier said than done - but try writing tests first. It is hard but gets easier and even enjoyable!

Comment: I have way more tests. I just ended up wanting to refactor so that the price_change method called the other methods automatically. I do test too much at once though. Great advice. Thank you for your time!